# Ember - best way to test on-change function dropdown

Tags: javascript, ember

I am writing an ember acceptance test. I have a text area that will trigger a drop-down each time a new character is entered.

I'm not sure what is the best way to test that the drop-down appears after each new character and that it contains the expected text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for specific elements with a wait in it.

1. Type in the text area
2. Wait for a dropdown element on the page to be present with correct values
3. Type in the text area
4. Wait for a dropdown element on the page to be present with correct values

If you need help past the logic please add specifics with the application under test and the test itself.

[Wait Helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/testing/acceptance/#toc_wait-helpers)